# How to fix 'Google services version conflict (Maps / FCM)'

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, google-play-services, ionic4, cordova-plugin-fcm

the problem happens after add google map plugin in this link 
    https://github.com/mapsplugin/ionic-googlemaps-quickdemo-v4

this google map work fine in ios but when I try to run it on android
get this error

```
[cordova] * What went wrong:
[cordova] Execution failed for task 
':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
[cordova] > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the 
version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest 
version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android- 
tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of 
com.google.android.gms to 10.+.
[cordova] 
[cordova] * Try:
[cordova] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run 
with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with -- 
scan to get full insights.
[cordova] 
[cordova] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[cordova] 
[cordova] BUILD FAILED in 38s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

    cordova build android exited with exit code 1.
```

I try all these solutions but not work for me but work for someone

1- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-processdebuggoogleservices-version-conflict/132560

2- https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/1093

3- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/execution-failed-for-task-app-processdebuggoogleservices-please-fix-the-version-conflict-either-by-updating-the-version-of-the-google-services-plugin-version-of-com-google-android-gms-to-11-8-0/125610

4- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-services-version-conflict-maps-fcm/93695/51

5- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-services-version-conflict-maps-fcm/93695

Answer (score 3):

The problem happens because I am using the old version from FCM plugin it works fine before adding google map plugin the conflict happens because of the 10.+ and 15.0.1 not the same and not compatible.

```
   cordova.system.library.2=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.+
   cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.+.
```

and

```
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
```

the solution is very simple and funny for me on these steps

1- uninstall fcm plugin using this command.

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated
```

2- install fcm plugin

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated
```

3- remove the android platform

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

4- add android platform

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

now everything is ok

go to android platform and open project.properties
 you found the changes 
like that

```
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0
```

now run

ionic cordova run android

I hope that helpfull anyone thanks.

Comment: This solution is not working in ionic 4.12, I am using Admb & FCM plugin. Please help....